# How does a concave function lead to cconvex inequalities?

Tags: probability, convex-optimization

I came across this in page 360 of Boyd Vandenbergh's book on Convex Optimisation:

[image: ad to convex inequalities?]

What is the meaing of the statement:

> It follows that a lower bound
> on the variance of $X$ can be expressed as a convex quadratic inequality on $p$

and how does it follow, it seems pretty unclear to me.

Comment: It means the constraint $Var(X)\geq c$ can be expressed convexly in the $(p_1, ..., p_n)$ vector, even though the constraint $Var(X)\leq c$ cannot.

Comment: @Michael great..thank you.